# Unicity of functions and their infinite expressions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages

While studying boolean algebra (where the lattice is over A={0,1}) I realized that I can have the set of all the functions from A × A × ... × A to A, the set A^(A×...×A). This set is finite, however i can write the functions f in infinite ways composing the other functions (to wich corresponds various algebraic expressions). I then realized that i can do this even in Linear Algebra by multiplying matrixes in infinite ways, in Analyis, etc... I don't understand clearly the relationship between the infinite ways in which a function can be expressed and their unique existence (seen as relations over sets). Is there a set of all the possible expressions over which an equivalence relationship is defined? (The quotient set should be isomorphic to the set of unique functions). I appologise for the bad language, hope that the answer was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is not an expression or rule, a function is just a set of pairs.
More precisely,
a function $A\to B$ is a set of pairs $(a,b) \in A \times B$ such that every $a\in A$ appears exactly once in a pair.

Some functions may be given by an expression or a rule.
Different rules may (and do) have the same set of pairs. Some (most) set of pairs that define a function do not have an apparent rule but still define a function.

The idea of *rule* is attractive but cannot work in all cases. For instance, one definition of *rule* is something that is obtained as a finite combination of primitives, such as addition, multiplication, mod, etc. Now, the number of such rules is countable but there are uncountably many functions $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$.

Have a look at these:

- [Recursive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set)
- [Recursively enumerable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set)
- [Primitive recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function)
- [Computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function)

Comment: Yes i know this, i was asking if there exists a set of all the possibile ways in which a function (set of pairs) is expressed. In Boolean algebra for example the function f(x1,x2) = x1+x2 is equal to the function g(x1,x2) = x1+ x1*x2 +x2 since they are equivalent to the set { ((0,0),0), ((0,1),1), ((1,0),1), ((1,1),1)} however they are expressed in two ways, and this fact is important since certain expressions are better (simpler) that others. I don't understand however what the expressions are, mathematicaly speaking (Using set theory).

Comment: I believe this is something related to formal languages.

Comment: Oh thanks, so there isn't an isomorphism between set of rules and functions if my set of functions has cardinality greater or equal than uncountable. In my case (Boolean functions) the set is finite so i belive that it may exist.